# Python client - connection being refused on locahost:9011

Tags: python, fusionauth

I am trying to setup FusionAuth with Django locally. However I cannot connect to localhost:9011 even though I can access the UI without any problems. The following is what I see when I try to get a user using the Python Client.

```
>>> client = FusionAuthClient("vwYJgvBEzLhu5C3XhIIDl2-qGro1LLe1su4OUJwddxw", "http://localhost:9011")
>>> client.retrieve_user("304bfe47-efb1-4da7-b25a-d1bbd1c7146f")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 83, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: I initially installed FusionAuth using homebrew. I installed it locally using docker-compose and have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. This had nothing to do with FusionAuth. I was using docker to run django and a couple of other services and FusionAuth was running in a different environment, hence the ConnnectionRefusedError.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Let us know if you need anything else.